# Return only data that have a full match across two tables

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT
    b.ID
FROM
    PLACE b
    JOIN ART_TO_PLACE a ON b.ALIAS = a.PLACE_ALIAS
    JOIN ART_TO_UNIT t ON t.MATL_TU_IDENT = :AUNITIDENT
WHERE
    (
        (a.GRP = t.GRP) --All GRPs must match, not just one
    )
FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
```

If there are some a.GRP that do not have a match in ART_TO_UNIT
or
if there are some t.GRP that do not have a match in ART_TO_PLACE
then do not return b.ID for it. Seek for the next PLACE entry.

How to do this without dynamic SQL ?

**Update**

Sorry, this should have originally been in the question. I won't now delete the upper part because two people have already replied.

Here is the minimal reproducible example for MS SQL Server because I do not have Oracle as a playground:

```
CREATE TABLE WorkplaceCapabilities(
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    WorkplaceID int NOT NULL,
    AllowedType nvarchar(50) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO WorkplaceCapabilities (WorkplaceID, AllowedType) VALUES (1, 'Wood');

INSERT INTO WorkplaceCapabilities (WorkplaceID, AllowedType) VALUES (2, 'Gas');
INSERT INTO WorkplaceCapabilities (WorkplaceID, AllowedType) VALUES (2, 'Oil');

INSERT INTO WorkplaceCapabilities (WorkplaceID, AllowedType) VALUES (3, 'Steel');
INSERT INTO WorkplaceCapabilities (WorkplaceID, AllowedType) VALUES (3, 'Wood');

INSERT INTO WorkplaceCapabilities (WorkplaceID, AllowedType) VALUES (4, 'Gas');
INSERT INTO WorkplaceCapabilities (WorkplaceID, AllowedType) VALUES (4, 'Plastic');
INSERT INTO WorkplaceCapabilities (WorkplaceID, AllowedType) VALUES (4, 'Steel');

CREATE TABLE TransportUnitContents(
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    UnitID int NOT NULL,
    ContainedMaterial nvarchar(50) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO TransportUnitContents (UnitID, ContainedMaterial) VALUES (152, 'Wood');

INSERT INTO TransportUnitContents (UnitID, ContainedMaterial) VALUES (25, 'Oil');
INSERT INTO TransportUnitContents (UnitID, ContainedMaterial) VALUES (25, 'Gas');

INSERT INTO TransportUnitContents (UnitID, ContainedMaterial) VALUES (122, 'Wood');
INSERT INTO TransportUnitContents (UnitID, ContainedMaterial) VALUES (122, 'Steel');

INSERT INTO TransportUnitContents (UnitID, ContainedMaterial) VALUES (13, 'Gas');
INSERT INTO TransportUnitContents (UnitID, ContainedMaterial) VALUES (13, 'Steel');
INSERT INTO TransportUnitContents (UnitID, ContainedMaterial) VALUES (13, 'Plastic');

INSERT INTO TransportUnitContents (UnitID, ContainedMaterial) VALUES (99, 'Gas');

INSERT INTO TransportUnitContents (UnitID, ContainedMaterial) VALUES (111, 'Steel');
INSERT INTO TransportUnitContents (UnitID, ContainedMaterial) VALUES (111, 'Plastic');
```

Now I would like to have such an SQL query that will return

- for the transport unit 152 - workplace 1
- for the transport unit 25 - workplace 2
- for the transport unit 122 - workplace 3
- for the transport unit 13 - workplace 4
- for the transport unit 99 - no workplace
- for the transport unit 111 - no workplace

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with: `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for your sample data; an explanation of what "all `grp`s must match, not just one" means for that sample data; and the expected output for that sample data.

Comment: [Oracle fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Rm7mOVzu). However, I'm struggling to work out how the sample data is related to the initial query because the initial query has 3 tables but the sample data has only 2 tables with different names and different column names.

Comment: I included only the details tables into the sample data. I thought to delete the first part of the question, but won't do it because two people have already replied. The first part really contains more information than is needed for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without sample data it is difficult to answer but it appears you want to use a `FULL OUTER JOIN` between `ART_TO_PLACE` and `ART_TO_UNIT` and then aggregate and use a `HAVING` clause to check that no rows were `OUTER JOIN`ed (and conversely then that all rows match):

```sql
SELECT b.ID
FROM   PLACE b
       INNER JOIN (
         ART_TO_PLACE a
         FULL OUTER JOIN ART_TO_UNIT t
         ON     t.MATL_TU_IDENT = :AUNITIDENT
            AND a.GRP = t.GRP
       )
       ON b.ALIAS = a.PLACE_ALIAS
GROUP BY b.id
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN a.grp IS NULL THEN 1 END) = 0
AND    COUNT(CASE WHEN t.grp IS NULL THEN 1 END) = 0
ORDER BY b.id
FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
```

or maybe:

```sql
SELECT b.ID
FROM   PLACE b
       INNER JOIN (
         SELECT a.place_alias
         FROM   ART_TO_PLACE a
                FULL OUTER JOIN ART_TO_UNIT t
                ON     t.MATL_TU_IDENT = :AUNITIDENT
                   AND a.GRP = t.GRP
         GROUP BY a.place_alias
         HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN a.grp IS NULL THEN 1 END) = 0
         AND    COUNT(CASE WHEN t.grp IS NULL THEN 1 END) = 0
       ) b
       ON b.ALIAS = a.PLACE_ALIAS
ORDER BY b.id
FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
```

---

#### Update for sample data:

##### Option 1: Using collections

Define a collection data type:

```sql
CREATE TYPE string_list IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(50);
```

Then you can collect the values for both tables into collections and join on identical collection values:

```sql
SELECT workplaceid, unitid
FROM   ( SELECT workplaceid,
                CAST(COLLECT(allowedtype) AS string_list) AS allowedtypes
         FROM   WorkplaceCapabilities
         GROUP BY Workplaceid
       ) w
       INNER JOIN (
         SELECT unitid,
                CAST(COLLECT(containedmaterial) AS string_list) AS containedmaterials
         FROM   TransportUnitContents
         GROUP BY unitid
       ) t
       ON w.allowedtypes = t.containedmaterials;
```

##### Option 2: Compare counts

Count the number of types/materials in each group in each table and then join and check that the number of matches is the same after joining:

```sql
SELECT workplaceid, unitid
FROM   ( SELECT wc.*,
                COUNT(allowedtype) OVER (PARTITION BY workplaceid) AS num_allowedtypes
         FROM   WorkplaceCapabilities wc
       ) w
       INNER JOIN (
         SELECT tuc.*,
                COUNT(containedmaterial) OVER (PARTITION BY unitid) AS num_containedmaterials
         FROM   TransportUnitContents tuc
       ) t
       ON (w.allowedtype = t.containedmaterial AND w.num_allowedtypes = t.num_containedmaterials)
GROUP BY
       w.workplaceid, t.unitid
HAVING COUNT(*) = MAX(w.num_allowedtypes)
```

For your sample data, both options output:

| WORKPLACEID | UNITID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 152 |
| 2 | 25 |
| 3 | 122 |
| 4 | 13 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Gam1wZ2C)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you could use nested exists conditions like so:

```sql
select *
from PLACE b
where
    exists (
        select 1
        from ART_TO_PLACE a
        where b.ALIAS = a.PLACE_ALIAS
        and exists (
                select 1
                from ART_TO_UNIT t
                where a.GRP = t.GRP
                and t.MATL_TU_IDENT = AUNITIDENT
            )
    )
```